# Atualizar objeto de um arquivo serializado

Tags: c#

estou com dificuldade e atualizar a quantidade de um objeto recuperado em uma lista de um arquivo serializado.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Estoque produtoEstoque = new Estoque();
        produtoEstoque.P = (Produto) comboBox1.SelectedItem;
        produtoEstoque.Quantidade = (int) numericUpDown1.Value;

        FileStream fs = new FileStream("estoque.xyz", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        List<Estoque> estoque = new List<Estoque>();
        if (fs.Length != 0)
        {
            estoque = (List<Estoque>)bf.Deserialize(fs);
        }
        estoque.Add(produtoEstoque);
        fs.Close();

        FileStream fs2 = new FileStream("estoque.xyz", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        BinaryFormatter bf2 = new BinaryFormatter();

        bf2.Serialize(fs2, estoque);
        fs2.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Compra salva com sucesso!");
```

Comment: Tem te gerado algum erro?

Comment: Sim, antes de adicionar um novo elemento no List estoque, eu preciso por exemplo verificar se o item já existe e se existir, preciso apenas mudas o atributo quantidade. Para isso fiz um foreach para verificar se o item já existe, é justamente no foreache que dá o erro. Fiz ele após o if de deserializar. O erro é esse: 

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Coleção foi modificada; talvez a operação de enumeração não seja executada.

Comment: Por favor edite sua pergunta acrescentando o erro.

Comment: Coloque o código do foreach, que acredito ser o mais relevante para o seu problema. Mas pelo erro descrito, você está modificando uma coleção dentro de um foreach. Sugiro trocar para um for comum que já pode resolver.

Comment: Você não pode modificar uma coleção (add/remove) fazendo um foreach nela